# terrible indentation issue (unindent does not match...)

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(self, message):
    message.content = message.content.lower()
    if message.author == self.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("big chungus"):
        await message.channel.send("Oh? You taunt me?")
```

Please ignore the content of the code... I'm writing a discord bot because the one written by the owner got defunct and one of its two functions was responding to "Big Chungus" (not in this exact way though).
I feel as if its either PyCharm being stubborn or me being a bit dense.

I have tried using a series of combinations of spaces instead of tabs but it always ends up with an error somewhere.

Comment: Please show the *exact* error message, and make sure that the code you post reflects the *exact* code you actually have, including whatever mixture of tabs and/or spaces you have. Telling us that there was "an error somewhere" is not helpful. At any rate, I can assure you that this is not "PyCharm being stubborn"; the indentation rules are mandated by the language itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try highlighting the entire code and keep hitting <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> till all the code is touching the left side of the editor. Then highlight the code in sections and hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to bring it back into its original indentation. Basically remove all indentation and add indentation again...

Comment: I didn't think that this would work because I had tried to redo the indentation before (manually, I had completely forgotten about shift+tab) but this did work! Thank you!

Comment: If it works, can you please mark the answer as correct?